# Retrieving Images using Net.TMDb in C#

Tags: c#

```
var movieResult = await client.Movies.SearchAsync("CitizenFour", null, true, 1, token);

foreach (Movie m in movieResult.Results)
{
 var images = await client.Movies.GetImagesAsync(m.Id, null, CancellationToken.None);
 foreach (System.Net.TMDb.Image image in images.Posters)
          Console.WriteLine(image.FilePath);                           
}
```

the above code throws an exception;

> error: sequence contains no elements) or or object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below seems to work but if there is another better way I'd love to  know it.

```
 var movie = await client.Movies.GetAsync(m.Id, null, true, CancellationToken.None);
 //Console.WriteLine(movie.Poster);
 var poster_Uri = String.Format("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{0}", movie.Poster)
```